# Redirect URL in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

Does jsoup APIs redirect the URL?

I tried 
`Jsoup.connect("http://mobile.testmifi").get()` which is not redirecting to `http://mobile.testmifi/cgi-bin/frame_main.cgi` though browser redirects the URL. or is there any workaround for this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `followRedirects()` method

```
Jsoup.connect("http://mobile.testmifi").followRedirects(true).get();
```

Comment: its not redirecting the url.